# python 3 password checker will only read the exact txt file content

Tags: python, python-3.x

My password checker is working however it resolves only when the user input is the same as the entire .txt file.

How can I put multiple passwords in the .txt file and have my program work if any of them match the input? I would like to be able to be able to add the password 123456 so that my second if statement will work.

> ```
> #simple program to check passwords against a txt file database
>
> passwordfile = open('secretpasswordfile.txt')
> secretpassword = passwordfile.read()
> print('Enter your password.')
> typedpassword = input()
> if typedpassword == secretpassword:
>     print('Access granted.')
>     if typedpassword == '123456':
>         print('This password is not secure.')
>
> else:
>     print('Access denied.')
> ```

the secretpasswordfile.txt only has genericpassword written in it.

Comment: Having plain text passwords ... even for mucking around ... should be avoided.

Comment: Try loading the password file into a dictionary with usernames and passwords.

Comment: I recommend researching into pbkdf2_sha256 https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pbkdf2_sha256&oq=pbkdf2_sha256&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l4.2773j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: **please, please, please** don't save passwords in plain text. It might pay of to watch [this fun video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q)

Comment: Thanks mate, that's a fair bit past my current expertise but will look into it as I get more proficient. For now, works social security number list will just have to remain in plain text ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every password in your file is separated by a newline, you can check if any of them match with this code. It uses the fact that you can treat the file object returned by `open` as an iterator for each line in the file and compares the typed password to each of these lines. the `.strip()` is to pull off the trailing newline from each line.

```
passwordfile = open('secretpasswordfile.txt')
print('Enter your password.')
typedpassword = input()
if any(typedpassword == pw.strip() for pw in passwordfile):
    print('Access granted.')
    if typedpassword == '123456':
        print('This password is not secure.')
else:
    print('Access denied.')
```